# How to check if a joint path exists before creating it using a for statement

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to use makedirs to create subfolders in an existing folder since I will have to create the same folders at least 40 more times based on projects but I want to check if the folders exist first in case I accidentally run the script twice on the same project.

I thought that maybe os.path.join.exists would work but I don't think this is real.

```
import os

mypath = r'path'

subfolder_names = [
    '01_subfolder',
    '02_subfolder',
    '03_subfolder',
    '04_subfolder',
    '06_subfolder',
    '07_subfolder',
    '08_subfolder',
    '09_subfolder',
    '10_subfolder'
]

for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
    # doesn't work but I need something to check first
    if not os.path.join.exists(mypath,subfolder_name)
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mypath,subfolder_name))
```

output it should put the folders or say "these ones already exist"  it would be nice if it would spit out which folders already exist and which ones don't.

Comment: You are pretty close. You need to join first and then check for existence: `os.path.exists(os.path.join(mypath,subfolder_name))`. `join` and `exists` are separate functions.

Comment: Like this:    for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
  os.path.exists(os.path.join(mypath,subfolder_name))
  os.makedirs(os.path.join(mypath,subfolder_name))    although this gives me an error if I hit enter twice saying it already exists...I don't even want to see that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. You need to join first and then check for existence:

```
subfolder_names = ['01_subfolder', '02_subfolder', '03_subfolder', '04_subfolder', '06_subfolder', '07_subfolder', '08_subfolder', '09_subfolder', '10_subfolder']  
for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
    p = os.path.join(mypath, subfolder_name
    if not os.path.join.exists(p):
        os.makedirs(p)
```

`join` and `exists` are separate functions.

You can also choose to do this functionally:

```
from itertools import filterfalse, repeat
subfolder_names = ['01_subfolder', '02_subfolder', '03_subfolder', '04_subfolder', '06_subfolder', '07_subfolder', '08_subfolder', '09_subfolder', '10_subfolder']
paths = map(os.path.join, repeat(mypath), subfolder_names)
missing_paths = filterfalse(os.path.exists, paths)
for missing_path in missing_paths:
    os.makedirs(missing_path)
```